# how can i set a state variable as component's property in react native?

Tags: react-native

i started learning react native and building an android app.so i have facing some issue with setting and getting a component's property.here is my code

i have two components named as content-container and bar-chart.
inside content-container ,here is my code block:

```
state = {
         barChartResponse: {},
         arcChartResponse: {},
         stackChartResponse: {},
         lineChartResponse: {},
         token:'abc',
        };


    componentWillMount() {
       this.setState({token:'xyz'});
}


render() {
   return (
    <ScrollView>
       <BarChart chartData = {this.state.token} />
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

now i am trying to get this property inside bar-chart component as follows:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        Alert.alert("ChartData is : ",props.chartData);

  }
```

it displays me value what i set in state object by default i.e. abc, but i want updated value.
please help me to find out what am i doing wrong....... thanks in advance.

Comment: define a `constructor` for `state` values. also move the `setState` method to `componentDidMount()`. Also, you'll need to declare `state` as `this.state={}`

Comment: Which react-native version you used??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `componentWillRecieveProps` but it is deprecated and in RN>54 you can use `componentDidUpdate` or `getDerivedStateFromProps` to get state from parent like this:

```
componentDidUpdate(nextProps){
      if (this.props.chartData !== nextProps.chartData) {
           alert(nextProps.chartData)
      }
}
```

or

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, current_state) {
    if (current_state.chartData !== props.chartData) {
      return {
        chartData: props.chartData,
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update state of parent component it will automatically reflect in child component but next time you will receive in componentWillRecieveProps(nextProps) then render method.

for example:

```
state = {
         barChartResponse: {},
         arcChartResponse: {},
         stackChartResponse: {},
         lineChartResponse: {},
         token:'abc',
        };


    componentWillMount() {
       this.setState({token:'xyz'});
}

updateState = () => {
   this.setState({token: "newToken"})
}
render() {
   return (
    <ScrollView>
       <Button onPress={this.updateState}>update State</Button>
       <BarChart chartData = {this.state.token} />
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

in BarChart.js

```
componentWillRecieveProps(nextProps) {
   // you can compare props here
   if(this.props.chartData !== nextProps.chartData) {
      alert(nextProps.chartData)
   }
}
```

Comment: Is componentWillRecieveProps(nextProps) a life cycle method or i need to call it from somewhere... it displays me a warning like did you mean componentWillRecieveProps() because it seems that this function is not calling...

Comment: its life cycle method you don't need to call it and this will be called once parent will get updated.